# Splunk - Grouping by distinct field with stats of another field

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have the following Splunk search that gathers the different Statuses from my dataset:

`some type of search | eval Status = (REJECT_REASON) | bucket _time span=day | stats count by Status`

This is a sample how my dataset looks:

```
CorrelationId      Reject_Reason    DATE_TIME
12345679           Accepted         20231030 14:00:00 
12345679           Accepted         20231030 14:00:00
12345679           Accepted         20231030 14:00:00
12345679           Sent             20231030 00:00:00
12345679           Sent             20231030 00:00:00
12345679           Sent             20231030 00:00:00
99399394           Rejected         20231030 00:00:00
99399394           Rejected         20231030 00:00:00
88393933           Accepted         20231030 14:00:00
88393933           Sent             20231030 00:00:00
33454545           Rejected         20231030 00:00:00
```

I would like to only get statuses for the distinct correlationId's, meaning that with the sample dataset I would only get back a count for 4 correlationId's and the statuses that are the latest date.

Example of desired result:

```
Status    Count
Accepted   2
Rejected   2
```

I have tried using "dedup correlationId" but it returned no results when I added that on to the search.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the desired result based on your sample. It's not clear from your description.

Comment: I have added my desired result. Thanks.

Comment: It seems that you need: `stats dc(CorrelationId) as count by Status`.

Comment: At first I copy/paste your snippet wrong but on second try your suggestion does exactly what I need. Thank you

Comment: Hi @PM77-1 I edited my sample dataset in the question because getting the desired result is more nuanced than I thought. Can you please take a look if you get a chance? I have a DATE_TIME field where I only want the status that has the latest DATE_TIME.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255810/discussion-between-pm-77-1-and-h22).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the latest (as of Nov 1st) requirements below is my query:

````
|makeresults count=11 | streamstats count
| eval CorrelationID=case(count >=1 and count<=6, 12345679, count in (7,8), 99399394, count in (9,10), 88393933, count=11, 33454545),
       Reject_Reason=case(count in (1,2,3) OR count=9, "Accepted", count in (4,5,6) or count=10, "Sent", count in (7,8)  or count=11, "Rejected"),
       DATE_TIME=case(count in (1,2,3) or count=9, "20231030 14:00:00", true(), "20231030 00:00:00" )
| fields - _time, count      
``` The above is test data setup ```
| eval Status=Reject_Reason
| eventstats max(DATE_TIME) as mx by CorrelationID
| where DATE_TIME=mx
| dedup CorrelationID, Status
| stats dc(CorrelationID) as "Count" by Status
````